# How can I fix "Insufficient privileges for IAM PassRole Action" when creating a BeanStalk application with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

When I try to create an elastic beanstalk application using CloudFormation, the resource creation fails:

`Insufficient privileges for IAM PassRole Action. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InsufficientPrivilegesException; Request ID: [...]; Proxy: null)`

How can I fix this?

CloudFormation template:

```
  BeanStalkServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                'sts:ExternalId': elasticbeanstalk
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth

  BeanStalkApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: Java Backend
      ResourceLifecycleConfig:
        ServiceRole: !Ref BeanStalkServiceRole
        VersionLifecycleConfig:
          MaxAgeRule:
            DeleteSourceFromS3: true
            Enabled: true
            MaxAgeInDays: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ServiceRole` attribute must point to the role ARN, i.e. `!GetAtt BeanStalkServiceRole.Arn` instead of `!Ref BeanStalkServiceRole`:

```
  BeanStalkApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: Java Backend
      ResourceLifecycleConfig:
        ServiceRole: !GetAtt BeanStalkServiceRole.Arn
        VersionLifecycleConfig:
          MaxAgeRule:
            DeleteSourceFromS3: true
            Enabled: true
            MaxAgeInDays: 30
```

Thanks to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17576